# Flink - Emit last window when there are no following events

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream containing events `Event(Id, Type, Date)` and I want to process those events grouped by (Id, Type) and session of activity

---

For instance, from events

```
Event1: Event(1, T1, 2018-01-24)
Event2: Event(2, T1, 2018-01-26)
Event3: Event(1, T2, 2018-01-28)
Event4: Event(1, T2, 2018-01-28)
...
```

I expect to have the following windows :

```
Window1 with Event1
Window2 with Event2
Window3 with Event3 and Event4
...
```

---

From my understanding, I should be able to do that with event-time session windows on keyed stream. 
But with my code, only the first window (Window1) containing the first event (Event1) is printed.

```
environment.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

environment
    .addSource(kafkaConsumer.setStartFromEarliest())
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(<timestamp assigner>)
    .keyBy(e => (e.getId, e.getType))
    .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.days(1)))
    .apply(new WindowFunction[Event, String, (String, String), TimeWindow]() {
          override def apply(key: (String, String), window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[Event], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
            var count = 0L
            for (in <- input) {
              count = count + 1
            }
            out.collect(s"Window $window count: $count")
          }
        })
  .print()
```

Is it the appropriate way of dealing with historical events and session windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case is that Watermark is always generated based on incoming events. If there is no incoming events than the Watermark does not progress. In your example only the Window1 is emitted because only for Event1 there is another following event with timestamp that advances Watermark beyond the session gap. For the remaining three events there is no such elements. For event3 and event4 there are no such events at all. Also because the stream is keyed elements with different keys are processed independently. Watermark does not advances in this case and therefore the windows are not emitted.

Comment: so if we have no more events the last session window will never be emitted ? and why window with Event2 is not emitted while there is another following event (3 and 4)

Comment: See me updated answer. Yes in general it is true, if stream stops and there will never be more events than the last session won't be emitted, unless you reflect it somehow in your WatermarkAssigner.

Comment: Some sources, when they know they have reached their end, will send one last watermark with Long.MAX_VALUE, which will close all pending windows, etc. I'm not sure if Kafka does this.

Comment: In my case my stream is keyed by user id and for a given user I don't know when the last event will be received (I just know that events for a user is not infinite). Is it possible to evaluate the last window if no more events come after some time (with a trigger) ?

Comment: Yes, I think you can write a trigger that operates both in `EventTime` and `ProcessingTime`. You could copy the `EventTimeTrigger` and extend it with the additional logic.

Comment: Based on the `EventTimeTrigger` class, I have registered a new processing time timer `ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(ctx.getCurrentProcessingTime + delay)` and kept a flag if the window has already been emitted or not. It seems to work. Thx

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.ProcessingTimeSessionWindows` is what you want. Different from `EventTimeSessionWindows`, `ProcessingTimeSessionWindows` triggered immediately after the `Gap` time passed, without waiting for next event come.